# Hide specific rows if range contains certain values

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have some help with automatizing my data sheet.

In the range of E7:V7 (hereinafter, r) I have same drop down lists, each of them has four different values ("-"; "open"; "close"; "both").

When `r` contains only `"-"`, I would like to have rows `21:50` hidden.

- `"open"` shows rows `21:30`
- `"close"` shows rows `31:50`
- `"both"` shows rows `21:50`

For example:

- if E7= "-", F7="open", then rows 21:30 are shown and 31:50 hidden.
- if E7="-", F7="both", then all rows are shown.

I hope it was clear enough.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("E7").Value = "-" Then
        Rows("21:50").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E7").Value = "open" Then
        Rows("21:30").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("31:50").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E7").Value = "close" Then
        Rows("31:50").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("21:30").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E7").Value = "both" Then
        Rows("21:50").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

This code works only for one criteria, but I hope it helps to clarify the situation.

Comment: Can you show your code so far?

Comment: If you did not start coding yet, start your research at the [Worksheet.Change Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change). Also the [Application.Intersect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) might be useful, as well as the [Select Case statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement). • Give it a try.

Comment: So the snippet you've posted does what you want it to do for column E, and you want to do the same for F:V?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in my comment: Use the [Application.Intersect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect), as well as the [Select Case statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedCells As Range
    Set AffectedCells = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("E7:V7"))

    If Not AffectedCells Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedCells
            Select Case Cell.Value
                Case "-"
                    Target.Parent.Rows("21:50").Hidden = True
                Case "open"
                    Target.Parent.Rows("21:30").Hidden = False
                    Target.Parent.Rows("31:50").Hidden = True
                Case "close"
                    Target.Parent.Rows("31:50").Hidden = False
                    Target.Parent.Rows("21:30").Hidden = True
                Case "both"
                    Target.Parent.Rows("21:50").Hidden = False
            End Select
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! It is almost the result I need, but for example if I select E7="open" and after that F7="closed", it hides "open" rows. Is it possible to keep both selections unhidden in this case.

Comment: Or for example one selection in range is "both" the the rows will stay shown, no matter what further selections will be. Thanks!

Comment: Of course you have more than one switch for the same logic. The last changed switch changes what to show/hide. If you want something else you need to re-think your logic. • Actually there should be only one cell/switch to show/hide the rows. Anything else doesn't make much sense to me. • Try to remove the 2 `.Hidden = True` lines from `open` and `close`.